# Sitecore: Detect user in Page Editor mode

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, page-editor

Can I know how to detect user is in page editor mode using code?
This is because, I have a component, when user browses from page editor, it will search in master_index folder instead of web_index folder.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please check with : `if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing)`

also is working on Sitecore 6.6, it not depends on Sitecore 7.

Please check also this Sitecore [blog post](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Martina-Welander-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/07/Improving-the-Page-Editor-Experience-Part-3-Detecting-Page-Mode.aspx) by Martina Welander.

To check if is normal page use:  `if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal)`

To check if is preview mode use: `if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPreview)`

Also are others PageMode:

- **IsPageEditorClassic**
- **IsPageEditorDesigning**
- **IsPageEditorEditing**
- **IsPageEditorNavigating**, etc

If you are curious you can check with Reflector or dotPeek this class: **Sitecore.Context.PageMode** from *Sitecore.Kernel* assembly.

Comment: Sitecore 8 switched to "Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor". And if you're using Glass, you can shorthand to "@IsInEditingMode" in the view.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than checking the page mode, I think you just want to piggyback on the context database name -

```cs
var indexName = Sitecore.Context.Database.Name + "_index";
```

Comment: I tend to agree. Although it doesn't answer the original question, it's a better solution to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this syntax in view to add a class for JS detection, same code can be used for back-end detection with bit modification:

```
<html class="@(Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor ? "inexpeditor" : "notexpeditor")">
```